# Sample one element from a set with O(1) time complexity

Tags: python, set, time-complexity, sample

I have a set in Python and I want to sample one element from it, like with random.sample() method. The problem is that sample() converts set to tuple internally which is O(n) and I have to do it in the most optimal way.

Is there a function that I can use to sample an element from a set with time complexity O(1) or the only way to do this is by creating your own implementation of set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the data layout is irregular, it’s impossible to *uniformly* sample from a hash-based `set` in O(1) except, in the case of ω(n) queries, by preprocessing it into some sort of array.  (Such an array could be maintained while building the `set`, of course, but that’s not the starting point given and isn’t faster to add than the `tuple` conversion.)